# Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0 issue

Tags: android

This problem is really annoying me since I have no clue what might be causing it. I have a few reports of this error, mostly from Samsung devices running Android 2.3.5 and 2.3.6 (98%). Below the stack trace:

```
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0
    at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:892)
    at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:580)
    at android.widget.TextView$HandleView.setOrientation(TextView.java:8355)
    at android.widget.TextView$HandleView.<init>(TextView.java:8324)
    at android.widget.TextView$InsertionPointCursorController.<init>(TextView.java:8631)
    at android.widget.TextView.getInsertionController(TextView.java:9218)
    at android.widget.TextView.onTouchEvent(TextView.java:7137)
    at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:3885)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:869)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:869)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:869)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:869)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:869)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:869)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:869)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:869)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:869)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:869)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:869)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:869)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:869)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:869)
    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1769)
    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1135)
    at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2096)
    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1753)
    at android.view.ViewRoot.deliverPointerEvent(ViewRoot.java:2227)
    at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1886)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Does anyone have an idea about what is going on or how can I add code in order to pinpoint the cause?

Comment: It seems the resource you are trying to refer is not available

Comment: See my comment below. If it was the case the stack would show the offending line.

Comment: how many reports did you get?

Comment: With the current version, 140 reports.

Answer (score 1):

You are try to set text in TextView??
Change

```
textview.setText(intValue);
```

to

```
textview.setText(intValue+"");
```

There are different versions of [setText](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setText(int)) - one takes a String and one takes an int resource id. If you pass it an integer it will try to look for the corresponding string resource id - which it can't find, which is your error.

Comment: That is not the case. As you can see, there no line of my code in the stack trace. Just from SDK classes. And I already checked all setText call. Notice that only happens to certain devices running 2.3.6. I have more 1.4 installs of the app.

Comment: There are so many Android devices with different configurations. So when we don't keep resources specific to corresponding matching device configuration[drawable-hdpi,values-en,layout-land etc] then android system looks into default configurations for that resource[drawable,values & layout].

So recommending to keep both default & configuration specific resources in respective locations.

Comment: Ok, but then a valid value would be reported not #0. Don't you agree?